# Inheritance in c++ and the "is-a" relationship

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am writing a simple hunter-prey simulation, in order to train myself in oop.

I wrote a class `worldBuilder` to generate a 2d array, where the prey and hunter can move around. This 2d array, which is generated only once, should be known to all hunters and preys.

My idea was to build a class `hunters` & class `preys`, which inherit the 2d array (the world map) from class `worldBuilder`.

On the other hand, I know that inheritance should be an "is a" relationship. For example "is a baseball player a person?" or "is a employee a person" -> yes! -> the class `baseballplayer` and class `employee` could inherit, e.g. name and age, from class `person`.

Neither `hunter` or `prey` are worldmaps. Of course I could pass the 2d array from main, but I want to this with classes and objects.

So how can I generate a single worldmap, which is known to all hunter-objects and prey-objects?

Comment: "My idea was to build a class hunters & class preys, which inherit the 2d array " - no, that is not wnat you want. You want to derive hunter and prey from a common base class, let's say "animal", and make the array be of animal pointers. The animals don't need to know about the array - something else does.

Comment: I find your example questionable, as being an employee or a baseball player is different from being a person. They are both transient and more of relationships or properties than essential parts of existence.

Comment: You said your goal is to train yourself in OOP but this goes against how pretty much anyone would ever structure inheritance. Have a common `entity` class which `hunter` inherits from and `prey` also inherits from. Pass in the world map by reference to the constructors if you want instances to have access to it

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like a design question.

In my opinion you should create another class with a member pointer to the worldmap call it "Entity" for example. Then make both your hunter and your prey inherit from that new class. That way both your hunters and preys will be able to access the same worldmap.